# How can I suppress "The tag <some-tag> is unrecognized in this browser" warning in React?

Tags: reactjs, warnings

I'm using elements with custom tag names in React and getting a wall of these errors.  There's a GitHub issue on the subject (https://github.com/hyperfuse/react-anime/issues/33) in which someone states:

> This is a new warning message in React 16. Has nothing to do with anime/react-anime and this warning can safely be ignored.

It's nice that it can be safely ignored, but it's still not going to pass scrutiny when my code is filling the console with useless error messages.

How can I suppress these warnings?

Comment: do you want to get rid of pollution in development ? because these warnings shouldn't appear in production build

Comment: it's a fairly large wall of warnings.  one for every type of element on the page.  I would like to get rid of pollution in development.

Comment: As of now, the easiest solution I've found is to prepend every possible tag with "x-".  There's some old hardly known rule about x-tags in html which says anything that starts with "x-" is okay to use.

Comment: What tags are you rendering in your components

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:**

see the answer from @triple with the correct solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55537927/1483006

**Orignal:**

I'm not saying this a correct thing you should really do, but you could hook `console.error` and filter this message by putting this somewhere before `react-anime` is loaded:

```
const realError = console.error;
console.error = (...x) => {
  // debugger;
  if (x[0] === 'Warning: The tag <g> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.') {
    return;
  }
  realError(...x);
};
```

It seemed to work on the [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/6xxn1wmr0k) that was posted in the GitHub issue you linked at least. :3

Comment: I'm no longer working on the project, so I can't verify this works, but it does appear to be a good solution to the problem.  If put behind dev env condition, it seems like it'll work fine without hurting anything.

Comment: It’s a hack, but I like it! +200

Answer (score 25):

I found a potential fix for this issue - if you are using a plugin (and potentially in other circumstances) you can use the `is` attribute.

Found [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11184#issuecomment-335942439) when working with X3d - simply writing `<scene is="x3d" .../>` works

Comment: Can confirm.  This should be the accepted answer.  I was also able to successfully removed the warnings by adding the "is" tag to my custom elements.  Any value works, for example: is="custom".  Even a single space is sufficient.

Comment: If anyone is here that tag being <text>, I could resolve it by using webview  like this <text is="webview">anything here</text>.

Answer (score 4):

My solution was to create envelope component which renders `<div>` with desired classes:

```
import React, {Component, DetailedHTMLFactory, HTMLAttributes} from "react";
import classNames from "classnames";

export default class SimpleTagComponent extends Component<SimplePropTypes>{
    baseClassName = 'simpleComponent'

    render() {
        return React.createElement(
            'div',
            {
                ...this.props,
                className: classNames(this.baseClassName, this.props.className),
            },
            this.props.children
        );
    }
}

type SimplePropTypes = HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>

export class MyTag extends SimpleTagComponent {
    baseClassName = 'my'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's a built in way to suppress the error message.

The warning message is logged right [here in react-dom](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/8a8d973d3cc5623676a84f87af66ef9259c3937c/packages/react-dom/src/client/ReactDOMComponent.js#L426). You could fork react-dom and simply remove the error message. For a change as small as this, perhaps using something like [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) would be useful, so you don't have to maintain a fork.

Answer (score 2):

React 16 gives warnings with x3dom components .

including is="x3d" in component suppresses these warnings.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. My problem was the new file for js when I use sfc I first letter of the name (tagname) has to be capital letter. I am just new so, I didn't notice it. But I am writing this just in case

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30236855)

Comment: May not be relevant ... but hey, I had the same symptom and this resolved the error messages . jb

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped my HTML in the `<svg>` tag.

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16135:

> I think you're probably rendering them outside of `<svg>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

This is what got rid of the Web Browser Warnings for me:

**BAD:**

```
const SocialMedia = (props) => {
 <socialmedia>
    return (
```

**Good:**

```
const SocialMedia = (props) => {
    return (
```